# Что нужно дописать в код, чтобы сообщения выводились по очереди?

Tags: java

Подскажите, что нужно дописать в мой код чтобы сообщение "введите оценку ученика по..." выводилось после того как я введу оценку к прошлому сообщению с клавиатуры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Urok55samost {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Программа считающая количество учеников имеющих шанс поступить ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("введите количество учеников");
            int n = scanner.nextInt();

            int m = 1;
            
            for(int g = 1 ; g<=n; g++){
                    System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по математике: ");
                    System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по русскому: ");
                    System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по физике: ");
            }

            int res = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 int a = scanner.nextInt();
                 int b = scanner.nextInt();
                 int c = scanner.nextInt();
                 
                if(a >=4 && b>=4 && c>=4){
                    res++;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("Подходит %d учеников", res);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно перенести ввод оценок в блок с их запросом:

```
int res = 0;

for(int g = 1 ; g<=n; g++){
        System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по математике: ");
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по русскому: ");
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println( g +" ученик:  "+ "Введите оценку ученика по физике: ");
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        if(a >=4 && b>=4 && c>=4){
              res++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое